# Is it okay for Flutter to log new frames every millisecond or so?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm developing my first Flutter application leveraging Firebase and FutureProviders, and somehow in my developer logs I'm seeing flutter.frames being outputted after every few milliseconds.

I cannot find much relevant info but I'm hoping this isn't a memory leak or some side effect as I'm still concerned about my implementations. Is this log so frequently okay?

`flutter.frame #46785`

`flutter.frame #46786`
.
.
.

If helpful, I am currently supplying my Providers like

```
FutureProvider<List<Sessions>>(
          create: (context) => StorageProvider().getSessions(), //Firebase call using a utility file
          child: SessionsCard(),
        )
```

Comment: Does the log appear when your app is stale?

Comment: if you mean sitting ideal then unfortunately yes, it does. Honestly at some points my devtools become unresponsive so it doesn't feel it lol.

Answer (score 0):

long update: seems like this was due to the way Firebase calls were setup in the project and how the tabs were unmounting views on change.